# How to automate a chrome extension and work inside it?

Tags: automation

[This is a screenshot of the zynbit extension i'm trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PALYJ.jpg) I'm trying to automate Zynbit extension for google chrome and validate it's functionality and work inside it but selenium is unable to to the same.

how could i automate a chrome extension and work inside it?

I tried this but error message appears saying no such frame.(BTW xpath and other syntax are correct).

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Sign In With Salesforce']"));     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

    driver.switchTo().frame(element);

    WebElement mn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".zb-frame.zb-ext-width"));

    driver.switchTo().frame(mn);


    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='zb-buttons zyn-cursor--hand']"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.click(login).build().perform();
```